# Use input value passed in from previous page to filter through a list on page load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, filter

Ok, this might be quite hard for me to explain, but I will give it a go. I have two HTML pages: form.html & display.html. The form page has an input which obtains a value and then puts it into local storage once the form is submitted. After the form submission, the user will be taken to the display page, which will then retrieve the input value from the previous page from local storage and then displays the value inside the input field on the display page. The display page will later act as a job page which will display a list of jobs which is filterable by the value inside the input field on the same page. I can get the filter function to work by using onkeyup on the input field, but I what I can't make work is the filter function with the input value from the previous page by using something like onload. The reason why I am using two pages is that I will later use this code on a website which will have a search box on the landing page, and then will be directed to the Jobs page with filtered results.   I am sorry if this was really hard to understand, I will post the code below so you might better understand.

Many thanks to anyone who takes time out of their day to help me with this problem, it is much appreciated.

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function passValues() {
            var firstName = document.getElementById("txt").value;
            localStorage.setItem("textValue", firstName);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="display.html">
        <input type="text" id="txt" />
        <input type="submit" value="Click" onclick="passValues();" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

display.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Tokyo Expat Job Search</h1>
    <input onload="filter()" onkeyup="filter()" id="result" type="text">

    <ul id="Menu">
        <li><a href="#">English Techer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Waiter/Waitress</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Developer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Banker</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Designer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logistics</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        function filter() {

            var filterValue, input, ul, li, a, i;
            input = document.getElementById("result");
            filterValue = input.value.toUpperCase();
            ul = document.getElementById("Menu");
            li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "";

                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }


        document.getElementById("result").value = localStorage.getItem("textValue");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the listener to `window.onload`? The `input` does not have such an event.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', filter, false)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I tried your suggestion, but it did not work for me. Did you get the code to work on your end? Maybe I put the code in the wrong place? I am not too familiar with the dom at the moment, I am still learning. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dwCreate It works on my end (I hope I didn't misunderstand it). I just put the code at the beginning of `script`, then the list will be filtered when you jump there. If it still not work for you, just try call `filter()` directly at the end of your script.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works. I just put it in the wrong place. Ha Ha! Again, many thanks for your help, it is greatly appreciated!